# How to connect custom click function on click on tag a inside header?

Tags: jquery-mobile

In JQM in header I put close button like (to be like on window on right upper side)

```html
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Data</h1>
        <a  data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconshadow="true"
        data-direction="reverse" onclick="close()"
        data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right"></a>
    </div>
```

I have defined simple close function like

```js
function close () {
    alert( 'close' );
}
```

but it never fires. ( I also tried to put `input type='button'` instead of `a` but it didn't work. I also tried to add id='close' and remove call from tag and add in `document.ready`

```js
$('#close').click(close);
```

but it also didn't work). How to connect custom click function on click on tag a inside header ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to the event like this:

```
$('#close').on('click', function(event, data){
    close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `"javascript:close();"` on `href`.

```
<a  data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-iconshadow="true" 
data-direction="reverse" href="javascript:close();" data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
data-ajax="true"
```

in your a tag.

## HTML

```
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Data</h1>
    <a  data-role="button" data-ajax="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconshadow="true"
        data-direction="reverse" onclick="close()"
        data-iconpos="notext"  class="ui-btn-right"></a>
</div>
```